# how resolve selenium server error on the chrome browser window?

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing django site using selenium but I am getting server error(500) on the chrome window.
this is what selenium reports back

```
devTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63521/devtools/browser/81f40775-3efc-4c51-a00b-3458fe4cd903
```

E

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_post_list_page (public-site-tests.functional_tests.blog.test_blog_list.BlogPostTests)
Lets create some blog posts
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gouth\PycharmProjects\work\teenstartup\pavan-staging\public-site-tests\functional_tests\blog\test_blog_list.py", line 43, in setUp
    email_field = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
  File "C:\Users\gouth\.virtualenvs\public-site-tests-ue9jU_Te\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\gouth\.virtualenvs\public-site-tests-ue9jU_Te\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\gouth\.virtualenvs\public-site-tests-ue9jU_Te\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\gouth\.virtualenvs\public-site-tests-ue9jU_Te\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="id_username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

the code that is resposible for this here

```
class BlogPostTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    """All tests related to Post model will be tested here"""
    def setUp(self):
        """Lets set up the browser"""
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        # lets set up some live urls
        login_url = self.live_server_url+reverse('accounts:login')
        self.browser.get(login_url)
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        email_field = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
```